# For loop last item issue

Tags: android, loops

I am using a for loop in another for loop, Problem is I want Left options, Right Options and answers, but only getting last item of each. how will I get that? Please help me out

```
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                    DataModel model = new DataModel();

                    jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    LeftOpts = jsonObject.getString("LQUESTION");

                    RightOpts = jsonObject.getString("RQUESTION");

                    Ans = jsonObject.getString("TRUE_ANS");

                    String[] leftItem = LeftOpts.split("@");
                    String[] rightItem = RightOpts.split("@");
                    String[] ansItem = Ans.split("@");

                    for (int j = 0; j < leftItem.length; j++) {

                        item1 = leftItem[j];
                        Log.v("Left", item1);
                        model.setLOpt1(item1);

                        item2 = rightItem[j];
                        model.setROpt1(item2);

                        item3 = ansItem[j];
                        model.setAns1(item3);

                        myList.add(model);
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < leftItem.length; j++) {
    DataModel model = new DataModel(); //move to here

    item1 = leftItem[j];
    Log.v("Left", item1);
    model.setLOpt1(item1);

    item2 = rightItem[j];
    model.setROpt1(item2);

    item3 = ansItem[j];
    model.setAns1(item3);

    myList.add(model);
}
```